# vBulletin Upgrade Database Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, vbulletin

I am trying to upgrade a `vBulletin version 3.8.7` to `5.1.10`.
I tried this by using

> php-cli command in my "/forum/core/install" folder.
>
> Eg: /forum/core/install$ php -f upgrade.php

But it displayed an error like this;

> Upgrading to 5.0.0 Release Candidate 1
>
> ---
>
> Step 16 - The table '#sql-2ff2_1a03' is full

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I would try asking this at the vBulletin support forums instead, as this is a vBulletin specified error message and not a generic PHP one.

Comment: @Oldskool; Ok thanks.